# Simple SELECT, GROUP, ORDER BY query not behaving as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I want to output the cities in my db and display the logo of the agents in each city (company_name is the name of the image)

In the screenshot you can see there is 1 agent in Head Office and 3 in Leighton Buzzard. The SELECT query below gives me 2 lines I don't need. I have changed the query to GROUP BY but all that does is remove the 2nd and 3rd results which then displays 2 results as I want, but only 2 Arpad logos. What I want is all 3 Leighton Buzzard logos to display under a single Leighton Buzzard heading.

I have tried using DISTINCT on the 'city' but that seems to stop the query altogether.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
"SELECT city, company_name FROM memberlogin_members ORDER BY city ASC"
```

[image]

```
$sql = "SELECT city, company_name FROM memberlogin_members GROUP BY city ASC ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $office = $row["city"];
        $agent = $row["company_name"];
        $coverage.='<div id="officeCoverage" class="fluid "><h3>' . $office . '</h3></div> <div id="imageContainer" class="fluid "> <div id="imageCoverage" class="fluid "><img src="http://arpad.property/app/logos/' . $agent . '.jpg" alt="' . $agent . '"></div> </div>';
```

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code too?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @IanPither There is an edit button!

Comment: Why was this down voted? I wish that I could down vote your comments @Strawberry, If you need a bit more info surely you just ask, just like the others did, I'm sure that the 'edit button' comment was because the code didn't appear as I expected it to, have a little patience and let me sort it out before posting negative comments TWICE !! within 10 mins of the original question.

Comment: SO welcomes feature requests all the time. You can also flag comments if you consider them unsuitable in some way. FWIW, I think my remarks above are informative. Incidentally, the 'edit remark' was in reference to your earlier comment - which I felt should have been an edit, and not a comment. Not sure why you're so touchy.

Comment: @Strawberry, sorry if I was blunt, obviously I was trying to solve 1 problem by posting on here in the 1st place, trying to see why someone was suggesting removing my signature image (which was a big part of the post) trying to understand the message SO gave me when I tried to reject it, then working out what SO, DDLs etc meant, David asked for the PHP code which I posted to comment then tried to find the edit button you referred to and try the result that Typoheads kindly provided, now I'm trying to work out what FWIW means, and why my question was down voted, sorry if I got a bit touchy !

Comment: For what it's worth, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT city, company_name FROM memberlogin_members ORDER BY city ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $currentCity = NULL;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $id = $row["id"]; 
        $office = $row["city"]; 
        $agent = $row["company_name"]; 
        if($row["city"] !== $currentCity) {
            $currentCity = $row["city"];
            $coverage .= '
                <div id="officeCoverage" class="fluid ">
                    <h3>' . $office . '</h3>
                </div> 
            ';
        }
        $coverage .= '
            <div id="imageContainer" class="fluid "> 
                <div id="imageCoverage" class="fluid ">
                    <img src="http://arpad.property/app/logos/' . $agent . '.jpg" alt="' . $agent . '">
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

You loop through the results, but only add the city headline if the city changes. If not, you just add the image.

PS: I would not use "id" attributes for the DIVs as they exists more than once in your HTML code.

Comment: Thanks again for all that @Typoheads I have it working exactly as I wanted it to now, If you don't mind, would you vote up my question as I think you understood it perfectly, someone else on the other hand voted it down within a few minutes... Thanks again for your help it's greatly appreciated.